# Windows phone picturebox

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1

I'm developing an windows phone 8.1 application in C#. I'm using the camera to take a picture. The picture is than saved on the device and I'm trying to show it in a picturebox.
I have tested it on a HTC phone and it worked nice, but when i tried it on a Nokia Lumia the picture would never load.
Does anyone have an idea how to  solve that?

Here is the code I am sing to take a picture:

```
    private void snap_task_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        cameraCaptureTask = new CameraCaptureTask();
        cameraCaptureTask.Completed += cameraCaptureTask_Completed;
        cameraCaptureTask.Show();

    }

    void cameraCaptureTask_Completed(object sender, PhotoResult e)
    {
        if (e.TaskResult == TaskResult.OK)
        {
            NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Slika.xaml?fotka=" + e.OriginalFileName, UriKind.Relative));

        }
    }
```

And this is the code where I try toload the picture.

```
    public Slika()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        string slika = string.Empty;
        string slika2 = string.Empty;
        this.Loaded += (s, e) =>
        {

            if (NavigationContext.QueryString.TryGetValue("fotka", out slika))
            {

                putanja = slika; /*"/Resources/" + slika + ".png";/**/

                int x = putanja.Length;

                if (x == 1)
                {
                    putanja = "/Resources/" + putanja + ".png";
                    uriPutanja = new Uri(putanja, UriKind.Relative);
                    fotka = new BitmapImage(uriPutanja);
                }
                else
                {
                    uriPutanja = new Uri(putanja, UriKind.Relative);
                    porukaTextBox.Text = putanja;
                    fotka = new BitmapImage(uriPutanja);
                }
            }
            img1.Source = fotka;

        };

    }
```

PS

the loading from local resources works fine on both phones, it is just the "else" part of the if that is causing problems on the Nokia.

Comment: Picture is saved in *CameraRoll* foder, you will have to get it from there.

Comment: i know that it is saved there, the string "putanja" contains the whole  path to the picture so it should work? can you please post an code example if I'm making something wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are saving the image in the Camera roll folder in your phone, try saving it on your memory card instead and try if that works (you an just change it in the setting of the phone and say to save the new pictures on the SD card) If that works, try using the PhotoChooserTask in order to get the image. 
I hope that the following code will help you:

```
    using Microsoft.Phone.Tasks;
    using System.IO;
    using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
    ...
    PhotoChooserTask selectphoto = null;
    private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        selectphoto = new PhotoChooserTask();
        selectphoto.Completed += new EventHandler(selectphoto_Completed);
        selectphoto.Show();
    }
    void selectphoto_Completed(object sender, PhotoResult e)
    {
        if (e.TaskResult == TaskResult.OK)
        {
            BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(e.ChosenPhoto);
            image1.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(e.OriginalFileName));
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thx for your help, it works now when I saved the picture to the SD card, I'll try to use your code now to select the photo

Answer (score 2):

You can try changing the UriKind from Relative to Absolute. If I have understood your code, you will get the absolute path to the picture.

Comment: I have tried that but it is still not working, I have also tried to set the UriKind to AbsoluteOrRelative but that didn't work as well.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand the code you have forgotten the .png in the else case.

Comment: I have checked that also, but the picture is a .jpg one and the extension is already written in the "putanja" string so I'm definitely sure that that is not the problem. Besides, it is working on one phone.

Comment: If that is true. It seems odd you have to make the extension in the first if case, but not in the else. That was the only issue I could see.

Comment: in the first if case I just had the name of the picture which is saved in the local resources, that is why I had to add the path to it and the extension, in the else part I have the whole path with the extension saved in the "putanja" string
anyway, thanks for your help :)